# Creating Triggers in my Drive vs Team Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth

I am having trouble creating a Trigger in sheets. The error I am getting is "Action Not Allowed" when the code gets to .create(). What I do not understand it I can run this code on a doc in myDrive but if I use this code in a Team Drive sheet it does not allow it. How can I create a Trigger in a team drive sheet/doc?

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
     .forSpreadsheet('id')
     .onEdit()
     .create();
```

I have also tired

```
.forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive())
.forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46323477/gas-doesnt-allow-pragrammably-create-installable-trigger-in-team-drive

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GAS doesn't allow pragrammably create installable trigger in Team Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46323477/gas-doesnt-allow-pragrammably-create-installable-trigger-in-team-drive)